# GetUser List PowerShell Script

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I am trying to pull list of the users from specific OU if LastLogon is greater 60 days from today.
Here is the script but it seems not working as expected.

```
Get-ADUser -filter {Enabled -eq 'True'} -SearchBase $OU -Properties * | Select UserPrincipalName, mail, LastLogon, Enabled | Where-Object {{$_.LastLogon -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-60).ToFileTime().toString()}} #| ConvertTo-Json
```

Not able filter the data based on date condition. Please help.

I tried below script at suggested by Abraham

```
(Get-ADUser -filter {Enabled -eq 'True'} -SearchBase $OU -Properties * | Select UserPrincipalName, mail, LastLogon, Enabled).where{$_.LastLogon -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-60)} #| ConvertTo-Json
```

Response: Error

```
    Could not compare \"132629184515770181\" to \"06/07/2021 22:21:36\". Error: \"C
annot convert value \"6/7/2021 10:21:36 PM\" to type \"System.Int64\". Error: \"Invalid cast f
rom \u0027DateTime\u0027 to \u0027Int64\u0027.\"\"
```

Comment: Does `(Get-ADUser -Filter {Enabled -eq $true} -Property UserPrincipalName, mail, LastLogon, Enabled).Where{ $_.LastLogon -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-60)}` work for ya?

Comment: Thanks for reply .. It did not work

Comment: I have updated result in original post.

Comment: $_.LastLogonDate and $_.LastLogon both has different value and it seems $_.LastLogon has correct date/Time

Comment: Ahh good catch @SnowCoder! I'm on my phone so was guesstimating it:)

Comment: The 18-digit AD timestamps, aka 'Windows NT time format', 'Win32 FILETIME', 'SYSTEMTIME' or 'NTFS file time' are used in Microsoft Active Directory for pwdLastSet, accountExpires, LastLogon, LastLogonTimestamp, and LastPwdSet. The timestamp is the number of 100-nanosecond intervals (1 nanosecond = one billionth of a second) since Jan 1, 1601 UTC.  
PowerShell uses property `LastLogonDate`, which is conveniently converted from the LDAP `lastLogonTimeStamp` into a Local DateTime object.
I suggest you use that property and compare like `$_.LastLogonDate -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-60).Date`.

Answer (score 2):

Try with this, my advice, don't call all properties `-Properties *`, only those you need to query and LDAP query is a lot faster than filtering with `Where-Object` or `.Where()` method.

```
$limitDate = [datetime]::Now.AddMonths(-2).ToFileTime()

$params = @{
    LDAPFilter = "(&(!userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2)(lastLogonTimestamp>=$limitDate))"
    SearchBase = $OU
    Properties = 'mail', 'LastLogonDate'
}

Get-ADUser @params |
Select-Object UserPrincipalName, mail, LastLogonDate, Enabled
```

Comment: THanks @Santiago, I think its working. Could you please help me to add && query to above statement. My requirement is to filter user inactive between 60 to 75 days, I want to run my orchestration to send reminders to those which are inactive less than 90 days and above 90 days, just disabled the user.

Comment: @snowcoder you're asking for something unrelated to the original question, my advice would be to ask a new question explaining what you need.